# Creating Executable Jar with Maven includes Jgoodies GUI

Tags: java, jgoodies

Im developing a java program and im using jgoodies for its GUI. I was making executable jar from my project, before developing GUI. It was working from command line. But when i developed gui for my project and made a package from it, it didnt work. It compiles successfully but when i tried to execute it, it throws errors:

```
D:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop\GPAT\target>java -jar gpat-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid unit name 'default'. Must be one of: px, dlu, pt, mm, cm, in
    at com.jgoodies.forms.layout.ConstantSize$Unit.valueOf(ConstantSize.java:349)
    at com.jgoodies.forms.layout.ConstantSize.valueOf(ConstantSize.java:146)
    at com.jgoodies.forms.layout.FormSpec.decodeAtomicSize(FormSpec.java:309)
    at com.jgoodies.forms.layout.FormSpec.parseAndInitSize(FormSpec.java:255)
    at com.jgoodies.forms.layout.FormSpec.parseAndInitValues(FormSpec.java:233)
    at com.jgoodies.forms.layout.FormSpec.<init>(FormSpec.java:159)
    at com.jgoodies.forms.layout.ColumnSpec.<init>(ColumnSpec.java:138)
    at com.jgoodies.forms.layout.ColumnSpec.decodeSpecs(ColumnSpec.java:177)
    at com.jgoodies.forms.layout.FormLayout.<init>(FormLayout.java:276)
    at com.alcatel.lucent.tr.gsat.gpat.GPATGUI.initComponents(GPATGUI.java:349)
    at com.alcatel.lucent.tr.gsat.gpat.GPATGUI.<init>(GPATGUI.java:31)
    at com.alcatel.lucent.tr.gsat.gpat.GPATGUI.main(GPATGUI.java:36)
```

I added the dependencies correctfully i suppose. Does this error make any sense for anyone? Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like your setting one of your form constraints to use the `default` unit, which JGoodies don't like.

Comment: I am using jformdesigner. I solved the issue now. The issue was occured from the code unnecesssary code that jformdesigner generated. Thanks for answer.

Comment: Don't forget accepting this answer (or the one you'll write to explain the how and why of this bug), as it willl have great influence on later answers to your questions.